# Ignore mouseover in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a control that has a thumb over top of it and when the mouseenter event is fired I want to be able to make some buttons show up of the control. This works; however, if I hover over the button or click the button and return back into the thumb this causes the animation to fire again because it thinks its a new mouseenter event. Is there a way of getting around this?

```
private void Thumb_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginStoryboard(((Storyboard)this.Resources["sb"]));

    e.Handled = true;
}

private void Thumb_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate()
    {
        ((Storyboard)this.Resources["sb"]).Stop();
    });


    this.BeginStoryboard(((Storyboard)this.Resources["sb2"]));

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

So the storyboard sb shows the buttons when the mouseenter occurs and when you leave the thumb the buttons are supposed to disappear. However, when you attempt to click on a button the mouseleave event gets called again...hiding the buttons.

Comment: Are you using WPF, winforms, ASP...?

Comment: Your problem might be that in WPF events bubble up.  Once you've handled the event, set `e.Handled = true`

Comment: this doesn't seem to help. The mouseleave event still gets fired when hovering over the button...

Comment: How did you implement the event trigger? In code-behind (via event handler), or in XAML?

Comment: edited - but to answer your question in the codebehind

Comment: If you do it in codebehind, you could use and maintain a boolean flag (a private field) that indicates when the buttons are shown. In your event handler then just check if this flag has the appropriate value indicating the buttons are already shown (usually you will set the flag to **true** for this case). If the flag is set then just bail out of the event handler without doing anything... (Don't forget to reset the flag whenever you hide/remove the buttons again.)

Comment: yea that's what I pretty much figured. I just wanted to make sure  there was something I was missing...

Comment: Is there a better way to do it in xaml where I wouldn't have this problem?

Comment: It's probably possible to do in XAML with the help of a custom conditional event trigger. But it would not be so easy, as you would need to suppress triggering of the MouseLeave event when the mouse moves over the thumb buttons. Since you already have the handling in code-behind, maintaining an additional boolean flag should be much easier and less effort...

Comment: Also, doing it in code-behind could give you some benefits if you want/need to make the UX more robust. Imagine the user moving the mouse from your control to the thumb button, but he does it in some sort of curved motion which causes the mouse to leave the control and moving over the background or unrelated controls before entering the thumb button. In such a case, the thumb button might perhaps be closed before the mouse reaches it. A timer that delays the evaluation of MouseLeave events and/or mouse position could help in such scenarios - trying to do this in XAML still requires code-behind

Comment: If you have successfully implemented the event handling and logic of the thumb button in code-behind, you might think about whether it would make sense for you encapsulating the respective logic in a custom behavior, which then could be added rather easily to a control in XAML (i am not sure -- i know too little about your project to judge whether the idea regarding a custom behavior would make sense).

Comment: I've only worked with behaviors once so it would be something for me to look into but your suggestion does sound logical and I will look further into it.

Comment: Could you show the WPF? Are the buttons contained in the Content of the Thumb control? If not that would be why you are getting the events fired again.

Comment: The buttons are on top of the thumb. Is there another way other than what @elgonzo suggested?